# Remove repeating characters from words

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I was wondering what is the best way to convert something like "haaaaapppppyyy" to "haappyy".

Basically, when parsing slang, people sometimes repeat characters for added emphasis.

I was wondering what the best way to do this is? Using `set()` doesn't work because the order of the letters is obviously important.

Any ideas? I'm using Python + nltk.

Comment: Essentially, I'm only doing this if a letter is repeated > 2 times in a row in the same word, so realistically the word would acutally be "haappy" by that logic. However, I could use enchant to spellcheck.

Comment: oh sorry, forgot I repeated the "y", yes, it would be "haappyy"

Comment: Matching against a dictionary is also a nice problem: find the shortest real word you can get by dropping repetitions. It's not trivial since some words have two or more double letters (think "bookkeeper").

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It can be done using regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(.)\1+', r'\1\1', "haaaaapppppyyy")     
'haappyy'
```

`(.)\1+` repleaces any character (`.`) followed by one or more of the same character (because of the backref `\1` it must be the same) by twice the character.

Comment: I would use `r'(.)\1{2,}'` instead so doubles are left alone (now you're just replacing them with themselves). That should give you another speedup.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Doesn't really speed up the substitution. My first thought was the same as larsmans' that regular expression should be much faster than group/join, but it seems to be not the case.

Comment: @Howard: It will if the string contains many double letters. Not on this test string, obviously.

Answer (score 8):

You can squash multiple occurrences of letters with `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> ''.join(c for c, _ in groupby("haaaaapppppyyy"))
'hapy'
```

Similarly, you can get `haappyy` from `groupby` with

```
>>> ''.join(''.join(s)[:2] for _, s in groupby("haaaaapppppyyy"))
'haappyy'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do it without reduce or regexps:

```
>>> s = 'hhaaaaapppppyyy'
>>> ''.join(['' if i>1 and e==s[i-2] else e for i,e in enumerate(s)])
'haappyy'
```

The number of repetitions are hardcoded to `>1` and `-2` above. The general case:

```
>>> reps = 1
>>> ''.join(['' if i>reps-1 and e==s[i-reps] else e for i,e in enumerate(s)])
'hapy'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it (limited to the obvious constraint that python doesn't speak english).

```
>>> s="haaaappppyy"
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x+y if x[-2:]!=y*2 else x, s, "")
'haappyy'
```