# Counting different names in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file and want to count few names on it. The problem is for one of the names, I have more than one name! what i can do to count them as one name and not different names?
For example:
LR = lrr = LRr = lrrs they are all same thing but when I want to count them they assume as different names.

Thank you

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not easy. And solution is simplified - first [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), then convert all letters to [`lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) and then [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) one or more `s` from end of string to empty string. Then remove duplicates - a bit modified this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10072826/2901002)(replaced to only one letter). Last [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

So if some words what need end with `s` there are replaced too.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

#sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'names': ['LR','lrr','LRr','lrrs', 'lrss', 'lrsss']})
print (df)
   names
0     LR
1    lrr
2    LRr
3   lrrs
4   lrss
5  lrsss

print (df.names.str.lower().str.replace('s{1,}$','').str.replace(r'(.)\1+', r'\1'))
0    lr
1    lr
2    lr
3    lr
4    lr
5    lr
Name: names, dtype: object


print (df.names.str.lower()
               .str.replace('s{1,}$','')
               .str.replace(r'(.)\1+', r'\1')
               .value_counts())
lr    6
Name: names, dtype: int64
```